# vim: How to join open/close braces without white spaces

Tags: join, vim, curly-braces

I'm little bit confused about formatting of curly braces.  Assume I have following text:

```
[
(
{
text
}
)
]
```

To join all lines, I pressed `JJJ...` and I got:

```
[ ( { text }) ]
```

Is this a normal behaviour? Why doesn't vim join `(` without spaces, whereas it suppresses white space for `)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help J` (scroll down a bit, or scroll up a bit from `:help replacing`):

```
These commands, except "gJ", insert one space in place of the <EOL> unless
there is trailing white space or the next line starts with a ')'.  These
commands, except "gJ", delete any leading white space on the next line.
```

I am not sure why it works that way--maybe it is convenient for C editing--but it is well documented.

Answer (score 4):

you should press `gJ` instead of `J`

`:h gJ`

and there is `:join` command. you need read the `:h join`

for your requirement, you could:

`:%j!`

or first select lines, then:
`:'<,'>j!` (vim will automatically fill the range `'<,'>`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but sometimes lines are indented as well.  `gJ` will involve these indented white spaces that I don't want.  I know some options listed in `:h fo-table` that can control white space(e.g.`fo+=B`) while joining texts but I can't figure out why `)` is special and `(` is not.